# Explicit Template Function and Method Specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I've been looking for a clear answer, and I'm just catching bits and pieces from the web.

I've got a function, and it needs to act differently based on a type variable.  The function takes no arguments, so overloading doesn't work, leading to template specialization.  E.g.:

```
//Calls to this function would work like this:
int a = f();
int b = f<int>();
int c = f<char>();
//...
```

First off, is that even syntactically possible?  I feel like it is.  Continuing.

I'm having problems defining this function, because I get hung up on the syntax for explicit specialization.  I've tried a number of different approaches, but I have yet to get even a simple example to work.

Secondly, I'm trying to (eventually) make that template function into a template method of a (non-template) class.  I'll cross that bridge when I come to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is possible but is not one of the nicer things to do. Explicit template function specializations are somewhat of a dark corner, but here is how you do it:

```
template< typename T > int f(){ ... }

template<> int f<int>(){ ... }
template<> int f<char>(){ ... }
```

Some related reading: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm

Comment: Thanks.  I had guess-tried this, but my linker kept saying that there were multiply defined symbols?

Comment: You wrote those in a header and included from several translation units? An explicit specialization of a template function is like a regular function in that sense. You would have to either define them `inline` or within an unnamed namespace (the C++ `static` equivalent). Otherwise just declare them in a header and define them in a cpp file.

Comment: Yes in header; but with include guards.  I was able to get it working with an unnamed namespace xor inlining.  However, when I go for my second problem (turning it into a method) it's failing again (trying inlining).  As far as putting it in a .cpp file, iirc weren't there problems with separating templates from implementation in C++?

Comment: Include guards prevent you from defining the same thing within a translation unit, but not from multiply defining it within several translation units. Show us what you are doing to turn them into methods so we can help you with that. There are problems with separating templates from implementation, but explicit specialization of either template classes or functions face no such problems as they are bounded to specific types.

Comment: I figured out how to adapt it for class methods.  It was mostly my error in changing it over.  The following link was useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416339/template-method-specialisation-problem.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

> First off, is that even syntactically possible? I feel like it is.

It is, but don't over-complicate things – this only needs simple overloading:

```
int f()
{
    return /* default, typeless implementation */;
}

template<typename T>
int f()
{
    return /* type-specific implementation */;
}

template<>
int f<char>()
{
    return /* char implementation */;
}

template<>
int f<int>()
{
    return /* int implementation */;
}
```

Comment: How would I define different functionality for int or char or whatever?  Sorry; perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @Ian : Then you would specialize, as in edit, or use compile-time constant `if` statements inside of the primary template. It's hard to give concrete guidance without a concrete goal...

Comment: "It's hard to give concrete guidance without a concrete goal." Yeah; I blame myself for that.  Your edit is basically what we figured out.  Don't see why the first non-templated function is necessary.  Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @Ian : The first, non-template overload is necessary in order for `f();` to be valid.

Comment: @Ian: That's simply impossible, sorry -- there must be some normal `f` overload in your code that you're missing. [Demo1](http://ideone.com/tRWZJ) (doesn't work), [demo2](http://ideone.com/Usjh8) (works).

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean.  The way I had originally wrote the question implies this, so that's my bad: I actually *only* care about the specializations (so that int a = f(); business will actually never be called).  But yes, as I wrote it, you do need that non-templated version.  Thanks,